# What CMS systems can be used with static code?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I know this isn't a coding question, but I've been googling and googling and I can seem to find ANYTHING on this topic...I can remove this post if you want, but I really, really want to know, so please give it a shot!

---

I have a website that I have been making (just writing HTML and CSS), and I want to have a page that is a blog, I would like to not have to rewrite code every time a do a blog post, but I don't want to use a CMS for my whole website.  Is there a way to use a CMS for just one page?  Or another way to simplify it somehow?

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should be looking at a more dynamic data system. CMS is an easy solution for this, but a bloated approach potentially.

If you simply wish to be able to use a static page template, and dynamically fill in the data, you could use a simple JSON file or XML.

Are you using Javascript, more specifically Angular or jQuery?

There are likely thousands of more ways to do this, but without better details on your project its a bit of a coin toss.

A really easy solution would be to simply create an AngularJS component and stick that in your single blog page html. Then, using an external JSON file only, you could dynamically populate all blog posts into the single template file.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <div ng-repeat="blog in myJson" class="blog-post">
        <ul class="blog-list">
          <li class="blog-post-item">
            <h3>{{blog.title}}</h3>
            <p>{{blog.body}}</p>
            <p>{{blog.date}}</p>            
            <p>{{blog.misc}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myJson = [{
        title: "Some title here",
      body: "Main blog post body here with <b> html content </b>",
      date: "Jan, 1, 2016",
      misc: "other info"
    },{
        title: "Some title here 2",
      body: "Main blog post body here with <b> html content </b>",
      date: "Jan, 1, 2016",
      misc: "other info"
    },{
        title: "Some title here 3",
      body: "Main blog post body here with <b> html content </b>",
      date: "Jan, 1, 2016",
      misc: "other info"
    },{
        title: "Some title here 4",
      body: "Main blog post body here with <b> html content </b>",
      date: "Jan, 1, 2016",
      misc: "other info"
    }]
})
```

And be sure to include the angular source in your index.html

[Here is a Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/alphanerds/HgDA7/171/)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm using JavaScript, but no jQuery or Angular at the moment.  I will look into AngularJS and JSON, but right now I have no experience in either.  Thanks a lot, this has been bothering me!

Comment: How do I include the "angular source"? I'm having trouble with it and don't know JS well, sorry!

Comment: To see what I'm getting and the code the code I'm using, please go to http://jeffarries.com/blog, it may be a rookie mistake, but something isn't working.  Thanks!

Comment: I got it working, I wasn't including the Quick ngRepeat correctly.  Thank you for you help and code, I wish you luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try perch, it's perfect for this use case.

https://grabaperch.com

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think I will try a free, coding option first!  But this will definitely be in my backup plan!   Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough, free = good :)

Comment: Yes, as long as the "free" is secure and private!